# Magento Connect problems on Linux

Tags: magento

1.

I'm running magento 1.7.0.2. Upon trying to install the "Blank"
theme found at http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/blank-theme.html
with Magento Connect (version 2.0, 1.0 did not work), I get the following error message:

"The server is temporarily unable to service your request due to maintenance downtime or capacity problems. Please ty again later."

This error message appears in the main area of the page as the only message, and
displays even when I try to display the admin user interface. I solved this problem
by reinstalling everything.

Later I realized that the default design package already has a theme
called base which is presumably the reason why this did not work (the
installation failed with a warning that widget.xml already exists).
Then, once I try to reload any of the pages, I get the following error.

2.

I also want to ask, how come does System -> Magento Connect -> Magento Connect Manager
ask the user to change every Linux directory to world-writable. Isn't it enough that
the apache group www-data have all (read,write,execute) permissions on every file.
After all apache runs with GID set to www-data so this should be sufficient.
Also, making everything world-writeable under the magento directory should
be a security risk, right?

Thanks,

John Goche

Answer (score 0):

1.
Have you tried downloading it again. I've noticed that the server hosting the extensions have had some problems.

2.
If your Magento directory is owned by the same user that is running PHP, you don't need to have world-writable permissions.

Mod_php, FastCGI PHP and php-fpm are all different and in some cases might not be running as the same user than your Apache server is.
One way to check under what user PHP is running is to create a script with `<?php echo $_SERVER["USER"];`